# Error while Cross compiling libpng for ARM: file not recognized: File format not recognized collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, libpng, directfb

While cross compiling DirectFB for ARM we need libpng as a dependency I cross compiled libpng and it is done successfully but while compiling DirectFB I get this error after make command

```
/home/vishal/new_dfb/DirectFB_LiTE/lib/libpng12.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [directfb-csource] Error 1
```

I tried the "file" command and its output is

```
file /home/vishal/new_dfb/DirectFB_LiTE/lib/libpng12.so
/home/vishal/new_dfb/DirectFB_LiTE/lib/libpng12.so: symbolic link to `libpng12.so.0.51.0'
```

And as libpng12.so.0.51.0 is present there so no problem for that.
Any help?

Comment: Are you sure you're linking to your cross compiled version of libpng12.so? I've seen this message when an ARM cross compile picked up a native version of the library.

Comment: you are right that libpng isn't ARM compiled. Thank You.